# Async function run in sync instead of async

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

I read this article and was trying to do the same https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/

I am looping through a set of entities in ODATA and trying to process them all in the same time (function Load() ).
My console app look like this

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    //List<string> dataareaidlist = new List<string> {  "cvl", "cpm", "hk", "ivp",
    //    "jp", "kr", "me", "na", "sh", "sp", "spb", "spec", "spfr", "spit", "spiv",
    //    "spuk", "tw", "vgh", "wec", "wge" };
    List<string> dataareaidlist = new List<string> { "CAIN", "CPM", "dat", "CGV",
        "HK", "JP", "MAL", "ME", "NA", "CVL", "SIN", "SPFR", "SP", "SPIV", "SPIT",
        "SPUK", "SPB", "THA", "WEC", "WGE", "TWH", "TW", "KR", "SPEC", "IVP", "MSHK",
        "MSSH", "VGH", "SH" };
    System.Console.WriteLine("Start program");
    List<Load> Entities = new List<Load>();
    DateTime startprogram = DateTime.Now;
    Entities.Add(new Load("SalesInvoiceLines", dataareaidlist));
    Entities.Add(new Load("SalesOrderLines", dataareaidlist));

    List<Task<String>> listTaskLoad = new List<Task<String>>();
    foreach (Load load in Entities)
    {
        Entity entity = new Entity(resourceUrl, load.Entity, connection,
            accessToken, load.dataareaidlist);
        Task<String> t = entity.Load();
        listTaskLoad.Add(t);
    }

    while (listTaskLoad.Any())
    {
        Task<String> finished = await Task.WhenAny(listTaskLoad);
        System.Console.WriteLine("Entity finished:" + finished.Result.ToString());
        listTaskLoad.Remove(finished);
        finished = null;
    }
}
```

The load function is async

```
public async Task<String> Load()
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("Start Load for entity:" + EntityName);
    //  GetNumberEntities();
    AnalyzeOdataLoad();
    TruncateStg();
    if (this.dataareaidlist != null)
    {

        Parallel.ForEach(this.dataareaidlist, (datareaid) =>
        {
            String url = resourceUrl + "/data/" + EntityName +
                "?$filter=dataAreaId eq '" + datareaid + "'&cross-company=true";
            Extract(url, 0, 0, 0);
        });
    }
    else
    {
        String url = resourceUrl + "/data/" + EntityName + "?cross-company=true";
        Extract(url, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    while (listTaskWrite.Any())
    {
        Task<Guid> finished = await Task.WhenAny(listTaskWrite);
        System.Console.WriteLine(" Task finished:" + finished.Result.ToString());
        listTaskWrite.Remove(finished);
        finished = null;
    }
    return this.EntityName;
}
```

So in the main program, the loop to start the function Load() start one by one (and wait for the whole Load() function to finish before starting the next one) instead of starting all the Load() at once. Not sure why it doesn't start all at once. I use the same login inside the extract function to load the db async and it work just fine.

Would appreciate any clue or link to tutorial that would help me understand.

Cheers

Vincent

Comment: What populates `listTaskWrite`?  Also if `AnalyzeOdataLoad` is loading stuff then it's a candidate to be async.  Note that control isn't returned until you hit an await in `Load`.

Comment: 1. You are misusing tasks. If you want to process stuff in parallel use the Parallel.For methods. I don’t see why you would need tasks for your code. The only part that were you would benefit from them is when call the URLs, but that’s where choose not to. 2. Parallel.For and tasks don’t mix well. It’s ok if your tasks are I/O-bound (like network requests). If they are CPU-bound (e.g. created via Task.Run) and you mix them with Parallel.For it can lead to thread starvation. 3. We don’t see where your async stuff actually happens, which seems to be `listTaskWrite`. How are these tasks created?

Comment: You have a type `Load` and a method `Load`, which is very confusing. Having variables that don't follow the [capitalization conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions) of the C# language (like the `dataareaidlist`) doesn't help either.

Comment: Thanks, But what what I don-t understand is whz this part does't start in parallel : 
foreach (Load load in Entities)
    {
        Entity entity = new Entity(resourceUrl, load.Entity, connection,
            accessToken, load.dataareaidlist);
        Task<String> t = entity.Load();
        listTaskLoad.Add(t);
    }

Comment: There is nothing `async` in your Load() method. But it looks incomplete , maybe you cut the important part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are confusing asynchronous with parallel.

- Asynchronous means "while this other thing is happening, stop running my code and let the current thread go work on something else"
- Parallel means "run these two (or more) pieces of code at the same time" (this requires more than one thread)

Asynchronous methods are normal methods: when you call them, they run on the same thread just like any other method. The magic happens at the first `await` that acts on an incomplete `Task`. At that point, `await` will *return* it's own incomplete `Task` and sign up the rest of the method to complete after that `Task` completes.

In your case, when you call `entity.Load()`, then `entity.Load()` runs just like it would if it was not marked `async` up until the first `await`. The only `await` is at `await Task.WhenAny(listTaskWrite)`, but you're not showing how `listTaskWrite` is populated, so maybe that code is never being hit. But regardless, everything before that `await` will run normally, as if it wasn't an `async` method.

You have a couple options. If you're making a network request in `Extract()`, you can change that code to make it asynchronous (all the methods in [`HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient) are asynchronous), then get rid of the `Parallel.ForEach`. In that way, it will start the HTTP request, and it will start working on the next request while it's waiting for a reply. All of this could all end up using one single thread, but you're using it to the full - it will never be just sitting there doing nothing while waiting for a reply. That's the best use of resources. That would look something like this (assuming you modify `Extract()` to be asynchronous and you want to use `listTaskWrite` for this purpose):

```
if (this.dataareaidlist != null)
{
    String url = resourceUrl + "/data/" + EntityName +
            "?$filter=dataAreaId eq '" + datareaid + "'&cross-company=true";
    listTaskWrite.Add(Extract(url, 0, 0, 0));
}
else
{
    String url = resourceUrl + "/data/" + EntityName + "?cross-company=true";
    listTaskWrite.Add(Extract(url, 0, 0, 0));
}
```

It is also possible to start a parallel job (run code on another thread) and wait for it asynchronously. To do that, you would use [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run). For example:

```
Task<String> t = Task.Run(() => entity.Load());
```

That will run `entity.Load()` on a new thread ("in parallel") and you can use `t` to know when it's complete. However, you will have to be careful with this kind of code. You're starting a new thread for each item, then using `Parellel.ForEach`, which will create even more threads. In ASP.NET, this is a bad idea since ASP.NET has a limited number of threads available to it. But even in any other kind of app, these are a lot of threads to start. You may find that the performance (time to finish) is worse doing this.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got my code to run.So if understand well,there is two options : First In the load I have one await and the Main thread will go back to the Main method ( I test that one it work). Second I can start it's own thread using Task.Run. For some reason I thought with Async they will fully run in parallel using the capacity of the server to have multiple core/thread. This program is a backend load program running on a large multicore server, I am trying to run as many task fully in parallel as possible.

Comment: Microsoft has some very well written articles about [Asynchronous programming with async and await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/). It uses an illustration about cooking that is a good one to help understand what asynchronous programming really means. That article is just the first article in the series. Look in the left panel and you'll see more under that heading.